# Telerik Line Graph Categories Null

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have tried everything I know to do but I cannot seem to get this to work...

My goal is to show tickets submitted in the past two weeks. I have already done all the logic on the back side of my MVC project but I cannot seem to display it properly. I just get a blank line graph with the legend to the right. I have provided my Razor code and the JSON return data. Please help. Thanks.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<NewTicketsTwoWeekGraph>()
                    .Name("TwoWeekTickets")
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Read(read => read.Action("NewTicketsData_Read", "Home"))
                    )
                    .Series(series =>
                    {
                        series.Line(d => d.TicketCount).Name("Ticket Count");
                    })
                    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                        .Categories(t => t.TicketDate).Date().BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Days)
                        .Labels(labels => labels.Rotation(-90))
                        .Crosshair(c => c.Visible(true))
                    )
                    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                        .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:N0}"))
                        .MajorUnit(10)
                    )
                )
```

JSON Return:

```
    {"Data":[{"TicketCount":1,"TicketDate":"\/Date(1426651200000)\/","TicketDateString":"2015-03-18"},
{"TicketCount":2,"TicketDate":"\/Date(1426564800000)\/","TicketDateString":"2015-03-17"}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the JSON data being sent back. It doesnt like be wrapped in the "Data" array.

So I changed up my ActionResult to fix this...

```
public ActionResult _NewTicketCtOverTwoWeeks_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string username)
    {
        using (var ctx = new GuardianContext())
        {
            var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
            var graphData = from ticket in ctx.TICKETS
                            where ticket.CREATED > startDate
                            group ticket by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(ticket.CREATED)
                                into a
                                orderby a.Key
                                select new TicketCount() { TicketCt = a.Count(), TicketDate = (DateTime)a.Key, TicketDateString = a.Key.ToString().Substring(0, 10) };
           return Json(graphData.ToList());
        }
    }
```

So now my JSON request returns the following...

```
[{"TicketCt":2,"TicketDate":"\/Date(1426564800000)\/","TicketDateString":"2015-03-17"},{"TicketCt":11,"TicketDate":"\/Date(1426651200000)\/","TicketDateString":"2015-03-18"},{"TicketCt":20,"TicketDate":"\/Date(1426737600000)\/","TicketDateString":"2015-03-19"}]
```